# Different behavior when sending POST Request through Java application and Chrome's POSTMAN Extension. How do I debug and find the mistake?

Tags: java, servlets, post

I am making a POST Request to a server with `Content-Type` set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. One of the query parameter has a value which contains `&` in it. I replace the `&` with `&amp;` before sending the request.

When I send this request using POSTMAN (Chrome Extension), the request goes fine and I receive the expected response. But when I send this request using a Java application, the server throws an error (unable to parse document). Here is the code that I'm using to send the request:

```
URL url = new URL(url); // url => "http://myserver.com/api/update"

HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(60000);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
printWriter.print(params); // params => api_key=abcd123&update_data_id=123&update_data_value=Test&amp;Value
printWriter.flush();

InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
String contentType = urlConnection.getContentType();

FileUtil.closeWriter(printWriter);

// Parse response ...
```

Here, the problem occurs in the parameter `update_data_value`. If I remove the `&amp;`, the request goes fine from both, POSTMAN as well as my application. But when the `&amp;` is present, only the request through POSTMAN works fine.

What could be wrong ?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It probably misinterprets the "&". Try replacing it with "%26"

Comment: I cannot use "%26". The API will only take "&amp;" as substitute to "&". That's how the server team parses the query parameters.

Comment: Are you sure the API will not automatically decode it? (You can substitute with "&amp;" but that still contains a "&") See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding. I don't know the exact syntax of a POST request, but I'm pretty sure it uses & as a separator, so you have to avoid it.

Comment: That's what the API guys said. The problem is that it parses fine when the request is sent from POSTMAN but does not work when it goes through my java application. So the problem must be there in my code. Maybe I'm not setting a required request header etc.

Comment: Did you actually try it? My guess is that that POSTMAN you are talking about does exactly what I am suggesting behind the scenes. I don't use chrome, so I can't check it. If you can't test it right now, maybe make a random POST request containing a & and monitor the traffic to see what it does differently. (Using wireshark, for example)

Comment: Yes I did try it. The response in that case is as if `&` did not exist. Requests through both POSTMAN and my java application is same, which it should be since the string now just contains "Test%26Value" in both cases. No parsing is done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58147/discussion-between-xandaros-and-shubham-aggarwal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long conversation in chat, the problem was this:

It's about a XML string, where an ampersand is used. The ampersand needs to replaced with "&amp;", according to the XML-Standard.

This XML string needs to be sent in a POST request, so the ampersand and likely the semicolon need to be escaped.

The final replacement string looks like this: "%26amp%3B".